# Buffering timed out when insertOne in a remote db

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, remote-server

I have a remote mongo server, and as far as I understand I can connect correctly:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-21T15:57:30.022+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20250,   "ctx":"conn102","msg":"Successful authentication","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-256","principalName":"test_user","authenticationDatabase":"admin","client":"x.x.x.x:56604"}}
```

But when I check the insert command from my test app, I get a ***buffering timed out***

```
[nodemon] starting `node ./dist/server.js`
Express server listening on port 3000
MongoDB connected
createUser
----------
err MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.setTimeout (C:\Users\_jmvelasco\Documents\node-mongodb-setup-test\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:184:20)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
user data undefined
----------
```

In the mongoDB server I can see these lines in the log:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-21T15:57:29.083+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4615610, "ctx":"conn90","msg":"Failed to check socket connectivity","attr":{"error":"The operation completed successfully."}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-21T15:57:29.083+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20883,   "ctx":"conn90","msg":"Interrupted operation as its client disconnected","attr":{"opId":92120}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-21T15:57:29.084+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22989,   "ctx":"conn90","msg":"Error sending response to client. Ending connection from remote","attr":{"error":{"code":6,"codeName":"HostUnreachable","errmsg":"Connection reset by peer"},"remote":"x.x.x.x:56530","connectionId":90}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-21T15:57:29.084+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn90","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"x.x.x.x:56530","connectionId":90,"connectionCount":17}}
```

Which I don't understand good enough to be able to figure out what is my problem.

My servers are Win2019 and I have the Inbound and Outbound rules in the mongoDB server for the default port. I have the mongodb server configured to accept external connections (bindIp set to 0.0.0.0) and set the authentication correctly since I get the connection from the webapp. But when check the POST method I get the error described above.

I have tried to play around different options regarding timeouts without success, and I have the keepAlice set to true (also checked without it).

```
private mongoSetup(): void {
    var options = {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        keepAlive: true,
    };
    mongoose.connect(this.mongoUrl, options, function (err, db) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('MongoDB connect error:', err);
        } else {
            console.log('MongoDB connected');
        }
    });
}


* mongoUrl = 'mongodb://test_user:xxxx@x.x.x.x:27017/' +
        env.getDBName() +
        '?authSource=admin'
```

Do I need to define some firewall rule in the machine where the app is runing (remote mongo client)?

Do I need to set up something in the mongo db server for the socket connectivity?

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. Update to the current version of all drivers you are using (nodejs etc.).
2. If that doesn't fix it, lower keep-alive interval in your operating system settings. See [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-create-client/#tcp-keepalive-configuration) for a description of the options, [this](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/MongoClient.html) for node driver.

Comment: it doesn't fix the issue, but don't know how it is working now. I just added types and restart vscode IDE. Very strange. Becasue I am a rebel, thanks D. SM

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappeared after adding typings and restar the IDE.
Quite strange to me.